# SQL Select where condition : value 1 <> value 2

Tags: sql, if-statement, select, conditional-statements, where-clause

Need your help to know if possible to select values from a table with the below condition :

Table content : matching between 2 objects
(Id_obj_A; name_obj_A; country_obj_A; Id_obj_B; name_obj_B; country_obj_B)

```
Select *
from table
Where (only if country_obj_A <> country_obj_B)
```

Many thanks for your help

Comment: what is data type? int?string?

Comment: Is it just a single table? If so, then there's nothing wrong with what you wrote, except the where clause is `WHERE country_obj_A <> country_obj_B`.

Comment: The data is on different tables: Object_A = entity Account on my data base Object_B = entity account on another data base used to verify entities info(Global database)

TableA: #Acct_ID,Acct_name, Acct_country TableB: #Acct_ID,Acct_name, Acct_country

Table C:#tableA.Acct_ID; #tableB.Acct_ID ->It contains the matching between accounts on both databases

So I need to extract the accounts that are not matching on accounts' country

I guess if I'll use a join between the both tables it should be with the same logic if we'll use one table, the condition should be the same ^^

Answer (score 0):

Yes. There are a few ways, one is to use `NOT EXISTS` like this:

```
select
       *
from tableA
where NOT EXISTS (
   select NULL
   from tableB
   where tableB.country_obj_B = tableA.country_obj_A
   )
```

or, using `NOT IN`

```
select
       *
from tableA
where country_obj_A NOT IN (
   select country_obj_B 
   from tableB
   )
```

or, using a `LEFT JOIN` then exclude the joined rows:

```
select
       *
from tableA
left join tableB on tableA.country_obj_A = tableB.country_obj_B
where tableB.country_obj_B IS NULL
```

Comment: Is the OP actually dealing with two tables?

Comment: Many thanks for your feedbacks ^^
I'll let you informed once I'll do a test (I'm having a troubles with my VPN connexion ^^ : So I cannot connect to the server to lunch the sql query )